# Reponder a minha própria questão após um curto espaço de tempo

Tags: debate, suporte, responder-a-si-mesmo

Hoje coloquei uma questão e alguns minutos depois descobri(lembrei-me) da solução. Durante estes minutos ninguém comentou ou respondeu, e após saber a solução eu decidi responder.

Porém achei que poderá ser meio estranho, perguntar e responde as minhas questões sem a intervenção de ninguém, até aprece que foi propositado (no meu caso não foi e nunca será, mas alguém pode).

O que sugerem? Respondo mesmo assim, ou neste caso é melhor fechar a questão?

Comment: Acho que não tem mal nenhum criares uma pergunta e responderes, mesmo que propositado, desde que a pergunta seja construtiva e que possa ajudar a comunidade.

Comment: Quando vc ver que tem um problema interessante que não tem solução aqui no SOpt, vai documentando o quanto antes, assim a pergunta e a resposta ficam legais (a pergunta costuma sofrer mais se não há documentação). Tentei fazer isso nesta aqui [Reduzir o tamanho de uma imagem e manter a proporção com CSS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32936/201)