# Uma meta tag para [self-answer]

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, responder-a-si-mesmo

Teve uma [meta pergunta recente marcada como duplicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2062/reponder-a-minha-pr%C3%B3pria-quest%C3%A3o-ap%C3%B3s-um-curto-espa%C3%A7o-de-tempo) e senti falta da tag <kbd>[self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-answer)</kbd> pra ela, pra duplicada e pra outra que não lembro qual. Até teria criado a tag, mas não sei como traduzir.

[auto-resposta](/questions/tagged/auto-resposta)?

[minha-propria-pergunta-com-resposta](/questions/tagged/minha-propria-pergunta-com-resposta)?

<sub>***Falando nisso***, não encontrei nenhuma tag de língua que caiba nesta pergunta... [estrangeirismos](/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos)?</sub>

Comment: Vc nao colocou nenhuma resposta aqui. A tag ficou sem sentido :)

Comment: Na vdd era uma piada. Como a gente está tratando do assunto em questão pode sim ser relevante colocar a tag. Ou talvez não, agora fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Vale a pensa rassaltar que a quantidade máxima de caracteres para um tag é de 25. Eu achava que era 30, por isso sugeri uma que ultrapassa esse tamanho. A propósito, temos várias sugestões que também ultrapassam :/

Comment: Só para avisar que agora as tags passam a ter um limite de 35 ao invés de 25. Link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/229289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## responder-a-si-mesmo        ?

Comment: Da minha parte, *case closed*, ok? Não sei se isto dá mais pano pra manga, e penso em começar a taggear as perguntas dentro de um par de dias.

Comment: Manda ver. Se for o caso, depois trocamos a tag. Não tem porque gastar muito mais energia com esse assunto.

Comment: -1 Parece que me estou a responder a mim e não a responder a minha pergunta.

Comment: Só por acaso pensei que era a resposta mais votada a escolhida... ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Ver comentário do Jorge B. acima.

Answer (score 3):

## auto-resposta                      ?

Comment: -1 porque pode confundir com resposta automática. Só existem comentários automáticos, mas bom...

Answer (score 1):

## responder-pergunta-própria  ?

Comment: É mais longo, mas acho que ilustra melhor, +1 aqui.

Comment: O que é uma "pergunta própria"?

Comment: É como "casa própria", e não é o oposto de pergunta imprópria. Também acho um pouco confuso. @math

Comment: Acho que a sugestão do Gustavo passa exatamente esta informação sem ser confusa. c/c @Math

Comment: @brasofilo a única que eu realmente gostei de todas aqui foi: **responder-a-si-mesmo**. Tb não gostei de **resposta-do-autor**. Que Autor? Autor de livro? Autor da pergunta? Autor da resposta?

Comment: @Math, bom, é uma tag aqui do Meta, creio que alguma certa familiaridade do leitor com o sistema é requerida.

Comment: @brasofilo mas que tal o **responder-a-si-mesmo**? O que não te agrada nessa sugestão?

Comment: @Math, acho que ontem eu tava com a percepção meio atravessada... [meta-tag:responder-a-si-mesmo] *me gusta bastante*, dá até um bom acrônimo RASIM

Answer (score 1):

## Respondida-pelo-Perguntador

Answer (score 1):

## responder-a-própria-pergunta

Comment: Muito boa esta aqui, é comprida mas não deixa margem a dúvidas. Podia ter esperado um pouco mais antes de criar a tag... bueno... pode ser proposta como sinônimo.

Answer (score 0):

## resposta do autor           ?

Comment: Acho confuso. Que autor? Resposta também tem autor.

Comment: Hm, é mesmo... Mas a tag se referencia a pergunta, e para alguém observar ela estará visualmente perto da pergunta não?

Comment: Na verdade estamos falando de uma tag aqui do meta, não do site principal. Ela serviria para marcar discussões ligadas a perguntas respondidas pelo próprio usuário que perguntou, e a discussão pode envolver tanto a pergunta, quanto a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

**respondida-pelo-autor-principal** ?